# ASF will not render Datepicker Addon fields without basic field type present

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

Forms do not render if only datepicker fields exist.

I am using the Datepicker addon.

The following does not render

```
//schema
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "date_complete": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "format": "date"
    },
    "close_date": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "format": "date"
    }
  }
}

//form
[
  {
    "key": "date_complete",
    "title": "Completed Date",
    "type": "datepicker",
    "readonly": false,
    "description": "Please Supply The Date This Task Was Completed.",
    "format": "mm/dd/yyyy"
  },
  {
    "key": "close_date",
    "title": "Close Date",
    "type": "datepicker",
    "readonly": false,
    "description": "Please Supply The Close Date.",
    "format": "mm/dd/yyyy"
  }
]
```

If I add a basic text field into the mix the form renders fine.

```
//schema
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "date_complete": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "format": "date"
    },
    "close_date": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "format": "date"
    },
    "basicfield": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
//form
[
  {
    "key":"date_complete",
    "title": "Completed Date",
    "type": "datepicker",
    "readonly": false,
    "description": "Please Supply The Date This Was Completed.",
    "format": "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "required": true
  },{
    "key": "close_date",
    "title": "Close Date",
    "type": "datepicker",
    "readonly": false,
    "description": "Please Supply The Close Date.",
    "format": "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "required": true
  },
  {
    "key":"basicfield",
    "title": "basicfield"
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Added this after setting schema/form in $scope.
Feels Hacky...

```
$timeout(100, ()=>$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormRedraw'));
```